# Genric in Java Error --> class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Comparable;

Tags: java, arrays, generics

### Question

Create a class named KeepSmallArray that uses an array to implement the KeepSmallInterface. Use the program TestKeepSmall to test your implementation.

Basically i have to drop the two smallest scores from the assignement.

### Key Points

1. KeepSmallArray object needs to be told at creation time how many grades (or whatever) it should keep track of.

### Hints

1. helpful if you make the array one space larger than it "needs" to be. For example, if it's remembering 2 grades, make the array size 3.
2. You need to keep the elements of the array in order. Consider using the insert algorithm.

### Error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Comparable; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.Comparable; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

### Attempted Solution

Tried error handling and changed some stuff around but that didnt help
however the problem seems to be in the constructor of the keepSmallArray class.

### My code

**TestKeepSmall**

```
public class TestKeepSmall {

    public static final int NUM_ASGNS = 10;
    public static final Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static final Random r = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int numDrops = 2; numDrops < NUM_ASGNS / 2; ++numDrops) {
            int numKeeps = NUM_ASGNS - numDrops;
            Integer[] grades = new Integer[numKeeps];
            int numKept = 0;

            System.out.println("\n"
                    + "Keeping the best " + numKeeps + " of " + NUM_ASGNS
                    + " assignments.");

            KeepSmallInterface<Integer> drops = new KeepSmallArray<>(numDrops);
            // KeepSmallInterface<Integer> drops = new KeepSmallHeap<>(numDrops);

            // test size/capacity/isEmpty
            System.out.println(" --> starts with size 0: "
                    + (drops.size() == 0 ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));
            System.out.println(" --> starts with given capacity: "
                    + (drops.capacity() == numDrops ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));
            System.out.println(" --> starts empty: "
                    + (drops.isEmpty() ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));

            // toArray
            Object[] dropObjects = drops.toArray();
            System.out.println(" --> toArray() returns correct size: "
                    + (dropObjects.length == drops.size()
                            ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));
            Comparable[] dropComps = drops.toArray(new Comparable[3]);
            System.out.println(" --> toArray(T[]) returns correct size: "
                    + (dropComps.length == 3
                            ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));
            boolean nulledOut = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < dropComps.length; ++i) {
                if (dropComps[i] != null) {
                    nulledOut = false;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" --> toArray(T[]) nulls unused elements: "
                    + (nulledOut ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));
            pause();

            // test add
            for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_ASGNS; ++i) {
                // get a grade from the user
                int grade = randomGrade();
                System.out.printf("A%02d grade is %3d.%n", i, grade);

                // see if it belongs on the drop list
                Integer keeper = drops.add(grade);

                // if not, add it to the kept grades array
                if (keeper != null) {
                    grades[numKept] = keeper;
                    ++numKept;

                    // test get
                    Integer newMaxDrop = drops.get(drops.size() - 1);
                    System.out.println(" --> \"bumped out\" largest value: "
                            + (newMaxDrop <= keeper ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"
                            + "(dropped " + keeper + " instead of " 
                            + newMaxDrop + ")"));
                }
            }
            pause();

            // toArray
            dropObjects = drops.toArray();
            System.out.println(" --> toArray() returns correct size: "
                    + (dropObjects.length == drops.size()
                            ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));
            System.out.println("\n"
                    + "Your dropped grades are " + Arrays.toString(dropObjects)
                    + "\nYour kept grades are " + Arrays.toString(grades));

            // toArray(T[])
            dropComps = drops.toArray(new Comparable[3]);
            System.out.println(" --> toArray(T[]) returns correct size: "
                    + (dropComps.length == Math.max(3, drops.size())
                            ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));

            boolean inOrder = true;
            int upperBound = Math.min(dropComps.length, drops.size());
            for (int j = 1; j < upperBound; ++j) {
                if (dropComps[j - 1].compareTo(dropComps[j]) > 0) {
                    inOrder = false;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" --> toArray(T[]) returns ordered array: "
                    + (inOrder ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));

            if (upperBound < dropComps.length) {
                nulledOut = true;
                for (int i = upperBound; i < dropComps.length; ++i) {
                    if (dropComps[i] != null) {
                        nulledOut = false;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(" --> toArray(T[]) nulls unused elements: "
                        + (nulledOut ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));
            }
            
            // contains
            Integer in = oneOf(dropObjects);
            System.out.println(" --> contains " + in + ": "
                    + (drops.contains(in) ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));
            Integer out = oneNotOf(dropObjects);
            System.out.println(" --> !contains " + out + ": "
                    + (!drops.contains(out) ? "PASS" : "FAIL ***"));
            pause();
        }
    }

    private static void pause() {
        System.out.print("\n...press enter...");
        kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static int randomGrade() {
        return Math.max(r.nextInt(101), r.nextInt(90));
    }

    private static Integer oneOf(Object[] dropComps) {
        int len = dropComps.length;
        int n = r.nextInt(len);
        return (Integer)dropComps[n];
    }

    private static Integer oneNotOf(Object[] dropComps) {
        int len = dropComps.length;
        int result = 0;
        boolean ok;
        do {
            ok = true;
            result = r.nextInt(101);
            for (int i = 0; ok && i < dropComps.length; ++i) {
                if (dropComps[i].equals(result)) {
                    ok = false;
                }
            }
        } while (!ok);
        return result;
    }

}
```

**KeepSmallArray**

```
 public class KeepSmallArray<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
    implements KeepSmallInterface<T> {

    private T[] smallArray;


    public KeepSmallArray(int len) {
        if(len <= 0) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
            
        }
        smallArray = (T[]) new Object[len + 1];
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        int count = 0;
        for (T item : smallArray) {
            if (item != null) {
                count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public int capacity() {
        return smallArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        try{
        smallArray = (T[]) new Object[smallArray.length];
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object obj) {
        for (T item : smallArray) {
            if (obj.equals(item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return toArray(smallArray);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray(Object[] array) {
        if (array == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("given array is not initialized");
        }
        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public T add(T newElement) {
        if (newElement == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("null cannot be added");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > size() - 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("index out of range");
        }
        return smallArray[index];
    }
}
```

**Keep Interface**

```
/**
 * A collection of "small" elements, sorted from smallest to largest.
 * The collection contains a limited number of elements (its capacity).
 * The client may request that a new element be added, but that element
 * will only be added if there is room for it <em>or</em> if it is smaller
 * than one of the elements currently stored in this container.  In the 
 * latter case, the largest element in the container will be "bumped out" 
 * to make room for the new one.
 * <p>
 * Such a container may be used to keep track of assignment grades to be
 * dropped from an average (for example, to track the two smallest of ten
 * assignment grades).  Alternatively, an appropriately programmed class
 * could instead track the eight highest grades from ten (tho' such a class
 * might better be called a "KeepBig" container).  
 * 
 * 
 */
public interface KeepSmallInterface<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    /**
     * The number of elements currently in this container.
     *
     * @return the number of elements in this container.
     */
    public int size();

    /**
     * The maximum number of elements this container can hold.
     *
     * @return the number of elements this container can hold.
     */
    public int capacity();

    /**
     * Whether this bag is empty.
     *
     * @return true if this container has no elements in it; false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty();

    /**
     * Remove all the elements from this container.
     */
    public void clear();

    /**
     * Consider the given element for addition to this container.
     * If there is space available in this container, then given element
     * will be added and <code>null</code> returned.  Otherwise the
     * largest of the current elements and the given element will be
     * "bumped out" and returned.  (Note that the given element may be
     * the one "bumped out".)
     *
     * @param newElement the element to add.
     * @return the element "bumped out" of this container;
     *         OR null if no element was "bumped out".
     * @throws NullPointerException if <code>newElement</code> is 
     *         <code>null</code>
     */
    public T add(T newElement);

    /**
     * The smallest-but-<tt>i</tt> element in this container. For example,
     * <code>get(0)</code> returns the smallest element in this container, 
     * while <code>get(2)</code> returns the third smallest element 
     * (<i>i.e.</i> the one with exactly two elements before it in the sorted
     * order).
     *
     * @param index the number of smaller elements than the one requested.
     * @return the smallest-but-<tt>index</tt> element in this container;
     *         OR null if there is none.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if <tt>index</tt> is not in the range 
     *         <code>0..size()-1</code>
     */
    public T get(int index);

    /**
     * Whether the container contains the given element.
     *
     * @param obj the element to test for.
     * @return true if it's present; false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean contains(Object obj);

    /**
     * An array containing all the elements of this container, in order from
     * smallest to largest.
     *
     * @return a sorted array with all this container's elements.
     */
    public Object[] toArray();

    /**
     * Returns an array containing all of the elements in this container sorted
     * from smallest to largest; the runtime type of the returned array is that
     * of the given array. If the list fits in the given array, it is returned
     * therein. Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of
     * the specified array and just large enuf to hold all this container's
     * elements.
     *
     * @param <E> The base type of the passed-in array.
     * @param array  the array to place the elements in.
     * @return a sorted array with all this container's elements.
     * @throws ArrayStoreException - if the runtime type of the specified 
     * array is not a supertype of the runtime type of every element in this 
     * container.
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified array is null.
     */
    public <E> E[] toArray(E[] array);

}
```

Comment: Why does `toArray(Object[])` just return its input? And why isn't it generic?

Answer (score 2):

So you can't use an array of Object since you are storing Comparable.  Instead, you need to use an array of Comparable.

```
smallArray = (T[]) new Object[len + 1];
```

should be

```
smallArray = (T[]) new Comparable[len + 1];
```